# How to add expression for AngularJS ui-select in ui-select-choices repeat attribute

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Before using `ui-select` I used simple `<select>` tag and I had there

```
ng-options="item as (item.name || 'custom name') | htmlToPlainText  for item in items"
```

Now I started to use ui-select and I want same experssion in `<ui-select-choices>` `repeat` attribute, but it doesnt work example:

```
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item as (item.name || 'custom name') | htmlToPlainText for item in items"> 
    ... 
    </ui-select-choices>
```

I'm getting error like

```
Error: [ui.select:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/ui.select/iexp?p0=Expected%20expressionNaNn%form%of%20'_item_%in%_collection_%5B%20track%20by%_id_%5D'%20but%20got%20'%7B0%7D'.&p1=item%20as%20(item.name || 'custom name')%for%item%in%20items
```

Is it possible to do or it's not supported by `ui-select` library?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write like this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in items"> 
    {{(item.name || 'custom name') | htmlToPlainText}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: Yes I now I did like that, but just curious whether it is possible to do as I described.

Comment: Have you run it what you described?

Comment: Yes and I'm getting some errors. I can post them if you want

Comment: I've added error, it says that it expect track by or something. I thought maybe there is some other syntax for this expression.